# Seeing missing global inbox

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox

For the last few weeks (months?), my global inbox has been going missing on occasion; perhaps 1-2% of SE page views. It looks like this:

[image: cn i haz inbox?]

This is in the current Chrome for Mac OS X, but I don't think it's a browser issue; maybe it's an Ajax transaction that occasionally doesn't complete? It's obviously not a big deal -- the inbox always reappears on page reload -- but it's mildly disturbing when it happens.

This never *used* to happen; I suspect it's something that was introduced with all the recent changes to the inbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your badge icons are also missing in that image, I'm guessing that the [sprite image](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=5) isn't loading properly. Hard to track, since usually you have to have your network tools *already* open prior to the occurrence to see what the status was for it, but it doesn't look like it has *anything* to do with the scripting.

Comment: Good eye -- I hadn't noticed the missing badge icons!

Comment: As the sprite is cached, opening the network tools, then clicking a link (to avoid a `If-Modified-Since` request) might tell you if the image indeed needed refetching or actually was in cache. This might indicate CDN problems with `sstatic.net`.

Comment: Also, you can see what is in cache. In Chrome paste as a URL: `chrome://view-http-cache/http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v‌​=5` (The URL must match exactly; the rendering in comments might add extra odd spaces between the `?v=` and `5`; alternatively go to `chrome://view-http-cache/` and search.) If that shows `RESPONSE_INFO_TRUNCATED` then some [odd Chrome bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=62712) is back.